# Open directory with an item selected

Tags: nautilus, default-programs

What I want to do is, open default file browser(`nautilus`) with an item selected. i.e From `Google chrome > Downloads`, if I click `show in folder`, it should open default file browser with downloaded item selected.

Now my question is, do all the applications (i.e `firefox, chrome, transmission`) call `gnome-open` or `xdg-open` to implement `show in folder` feature?

## Clarification

Nautilus is able to open a directory with an item selected if you just call this : `nautilus /directory/to/open/selected_item`. I am trying to figuring out that which `system call` or `command` execute during the click event of `show in folder` option, so that I can modify there if default file browser is `nautilus`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **no**, or I have understood you completely wrong.

1. `xdg-open`

   `xdg-open` is in the package `xdg-utils` and neither firefox or chrome or transmission depends on the package
2. `gnome-open`

   `gnome-open` is in the package `gnome-open` and also here, neither firefox or chrome or transmission depends on the package

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But there should be a system call for that I guess. Because like gnome-open firefox(chrome etc) always open system default file browser doesn't matter which one is default.